# Calling SqlDependency.Start two times continuously, the second time failed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker, sqldependency, sqlcachedependency

The purpose of calling `SqlDependency.Start` multiple times is to ensure it's fine before some other action such as creating a new instance of `SqlCacheDependency` based on a `Command`. According to Microsoft's document about `SqlDependency.Start` at here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.start(v=vs.110).aspx (the Remarks section), looks like calling `SqlDependency.Start` multiple times is totally fine:

> Multiple calls with identical parameters (the same connection string and Windows credentials in the calling thread) are valid.

But actually it can fail (and really it has never succeeded for me) for the second call, making all next attempts to call `SqlDependency.Start` fail (silently by returning `false`, no exception is thrown).

What I did should meet the first restriction (mentioned in the Remarks section in the above link), that is all the calls to `SqlDependency.Start` have the same parameters (in fact there was just 1 same parameter which is the connection string). It looks just like this:

```
//at initialization step (such as in `Application_Start()` in ASP.NET MVC)
SqlDependency.Start(myConnectionString);//this usually returns OK 
//later at the time before creating an instance of SqlCacheDependency
//I tried to call the Start method again to ensure everything is ok
var ok = SqlDependency.Start(myConnectionString);//almost always false
if(ok){
    //almost never reach here ...
}
```

So it's really hard to understand about what stated by Microsoft (in the first restriction in the Remarks section), the 2 calls are exactly the same. But with the second call failed, any that same call used after that will still fail (meaning there is not any chance to start it successfully once I attempted to call it more than once).

When I see the log in Sql Server I can see that there are a lot of messages saying something like *Cannot find the remote service ... because it does not exist*

I don't need a solution or work-around this problem, I just need some explanation to why it does not work expectedly like what Microsoft stated, or I misunderstood what stated by Microsoft?

Comment: The call didn't fail. Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms224872), it returns "`true` if the listener initialized successfully; `false` if a compatible listener already exists." The dependency may not work correctly (and that's quite possible, the setup is quite involved) but the second call is returning `false` because the framework does think everything is working and there's no need to start again.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for your quick response. Really I did not know about that, but maybe the reason is it did not work (if I remove the `if(ok)` and just proceed to create a new instance of `SqlCacheDependency` then it will throw exception and recommend me to ensure to call `SqlDependency.Start` before??? And as I said, the log shows that it did not work. Thanks!

Comment: In the background, `SqlDependency` jumps through a lot of hoops to get the dependency working. Internally, it involves setting up a service broker queue plus conversation on SQL Server to which notifications can be delivered, and the error message you quote is likely a result of that. Troubleshooting that may be quite involved, requiring a profiler trace. I'm not intimately familiar with how query notifications work under the covers (I tried them once but found them too unreliable for my always-on application).

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually I'm confused about the time I saw the log. I mean actually there was one more stupid thing I added to my code (to the `Dispose()` override of my MvcApplication and what I added is a call to `SqlDependency.Stop`. Maybe that's what actually causing the issue, but at the time removing that and trying using `if` to attempt to calling `Start` before creating SqlDependency instances, because of my thought `ok` should be true to proceed, otherwise log an error. Yes at that time I did not notice the error logged by Sql Server and instead focus on my log. Maybe it's just my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916) mentioned in the comments and the docs for [`SqlCommand.Start()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.start?view=netframework-4.7.2) state:

> Returns
>
> [`Boolean`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.boolean?view=netframework-4.7.2)
>
> `true` if the listener initialized successfully; `false` if a compatible listener already exists.

As the remarks in the docs describe, `SqlDependency.Start()` and `SqlDependency.Stop()` will keep track of the number of calls to each one. It will ensure a background connection is running or being set up if the number of calls to `SqlDependency.Start()` exceeds the number of calls to `SqlDependency.Stop()` (though I think it loses track and resets its count if you call `SqlDependency.Stop()` more times than than you call `SqlDependency.Start()`).

### `Start()` Errors

It may help to clarify that it is possible for `SqlDependency.Start()` to fail. One way to get it to fail is to call it multiple times from one `AppDomain` with different connection strings. Within a particular `AppDomain`, `SqlDependency.Start()` will **throw an exception** if you pass in a different connection string unless if at least one of the following properties in the connection string is different from a previously passed connection string:

1. Database name
2. Username

I.e., you are expected to normalize or cache the connection string you first pass to `SqlDependency.Start()` so that you never pass it a string that has, for example, a different value for `Max Pool Size`. I think it does this to try to avoid creating a lot of broker queues and connections for a single process. Additionally, when it tries to match up a command to a broker queue when you actually set up an `SqlDependency` later, it probably uses these distinguishing connection string properties to decide which queue to use.

### ASP.NET Life Cycle

From the [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx#Anchor_1) documentation under “Life Cycle Events and the Global.asax file”, note the following:

The `Application_Start` method, while an instance method, is called only when the application is starting which often occurs during the first HTTP request for your application. The documentation specifically states:

> You should set only static data during application start. Do not set any instance data because it will be available only to the first instance of the [`HttpApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) class that is created.

The method you should use to clean up things which you initialized in `Application_Start` is `Application_End`. When a webapp is gracefully stopped, an instance of your application class will be created and `Application_End` called on it. Note that this might be a different instance of the application class than `Application_Start` was called on.

Because of ASP.NET’s architecture, a distinct `HttpApplication` class instance is required for each request that is processing. That means that multiple instances will be created to handle concurrent requests. The docs also state that, for performance reasons, application class instances **may** be cached by the framework and used for multiple requests. To give you an opportunity to initialize and cleanup your application class at an instance level, you may implement `Init` and `Dispose` methods. These methods should configure the application class’s instance variables that are not specific to a particular requests. The docs state:

> [`Init`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.init.aspx)
>
> Called once for every instance of the `HttpApplication` class after all modules have been created.
>
> [`Dispose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.dispose.aspx)
>
> Called before the application instance is destroyed.

However, you mentioned that you were initializing global state (i.e., `SqlDependency.Start()`) in `Application_Start` and cleaning up global state (i.e., `SqlDependency.Stop()`) in `Dispose()`. Due to the fact that `Application_Start` will be called once and is intended for configuring statics/globals and `Dispose()` is called for each application class instance that the framework retires (which may happen multiple times before `Application_End()` is called), it is likely that you are stopping the dependency quickly.

Thus, it may be that `SqlDependency.Stop()` is called after the server runs out of requests, in which case it would clean up the `HttpApplication` instance by calling `Dispose()`. Any attempts to actually start monitoring for changes by attaching an `SqlDependency` to an `SqlCommand` should likely fail at after that. I am not sure what already-subscribed commands will do, but they may fail at that point which would trigger your code to resubscribe a new dependency which should then hit an error. This could be the explanation for your “Cannot find the remote service” errors—you called `SqlDependency.Stop()` too early and too often.

Comment: this contains a lot of helpful info, thank you. Although I don't quite remember how my problem was resolved, looks like it almost involved the call to `SqlDependency.Stop`. It's kind of ridiculous about the `SqlDependency.Start`, looks like regardless of its return value (true or false), the Sql Dependency should be ready after that unless there is some exception. So looks like we need to use try/catch instead to know if it actually succeeds.